# Could you parse "She was younger than any of us had figured on"?

Tags: parsing, comparative

an example of "to figure on something" from [ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/figure-on):
*She was younger than any of us had figured on*.

So, the phrase is "to figure on X".
But where is the X in this sentence?
The subordinate clause looks like a strange mix of a relative clause and a comparative clause.
Could you parse this sentence please?

Answer (score 1):

As with the gloss "expected", this can take a complex complement  "figure on her to do something" or "her doing something". There is a non-finite complement.

Your sentence could be paraphrased as "We figured on her being older".

The transitive verb "expect" can be used in such a construction without an explicit object:

> She was younger than we had expected.

and gain the meaning is "We expected her to be older".

Comment: If "_She was younger than any of us had figured **on**_." is correct with "_on_", therefore "_She was younger than any of us had hoped **for**_." is correct with "_for_", right? Thanks.

Comment: yes...............................